How to solve the problem that the dropdown list of ttk.Combobox remains visible after Alt+Tab in Win10
After clicking on the combobox, the dropdown list is shown.
Press Alt+Tab (Win10) to switch to other application and find that the dropdown list remains visible while the test application itself is hidden.
Also there is no <FocusOut> event received for root or combo itself.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")

combo = ttk.Combobox(root, state="readonly")
combo['values'] = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
combo.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: root.after(2000, lambda: webbrowser.open("https://stackoverflow.com")))
combo.pack()

root.mainloop()

With Python 3.12.4
Before Alt+Tab:

After Alt+Tab:

I expect the dropdown disappears along with the test application itself. Also I'd like to receive <FocusOut> event for root

This may be a bit of brute force, but you could try redirecting focus to the root window when the Alt key is pressed. This way, the combobox menu closes as soon as the keypress is detected.
bind_all is used here in order to bind to the children of combo as well (i.e., the menu window).
combo.bind_all('<Alt_L>', lambda _: root.focus())

Note that you'll probably also want to add a binding for '<Alt_R>'

Thanks @JRiggles! That actually works fine for Alt+Tab.
However I have a new situation popped up:

If I have the dropdown list shown and the application launches a browser, the similar issue happens
combo.bind_all('<Alt_L>', ...) doesn't apply in this case


Glad I could help. If this worked out for you, please mark the answer as 'Accepted' so that others know this question has been answered.

I marked the original question as answer.
I am looking for any solution to the other issue encountered. The example code was updated to reproduce the new issue.

If you've added new code to produce a second issue, you should post that as a separate question altogether.

FYI I posted another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78603621/how-to-solve-the-problem-that-the-dropdown-list-of-ttk-combobox-remains-visible
